# springboot how to unit test the path variables in a url pattern

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test a url pattern and check if the values are correctly assigned to the pathvariables

if the pattern is /hello/{x}/world/{y}. I want to write a test that when a url like /hello/beautiful/world/yet is passed then x is "beautiful" and y is "yet". This is a simplistic example, I want to test more regex based url and their path variables.

MockMvcResultMatchers seems to be used to test the result.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the following to test the URL

```
@WebMvcTest(MyMvcController.class)
public class MyWebAppTest {
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void testRequest() throws Exception {
    ServletContext context = new MockServletContext();
    MockHttpServletRequest request =  MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/modules/test/sayHi/{abc}","hello").buildRequest(context);
    String url = request.getRequestURI();
    assertEquals(url,"/modules/test/sayHi/hello");
  }
}
```